# Passing SWT Control reference to Enum

Tags: java, enums, eclipse-rcp, object-reference

### My Setup

I have some code in an Eclipse RCP application that looks like this (it is in the `@PostConstruct` method of a Part):

```
scroll = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
taskingInputsGroup = new Composite(scroll, SWT.NONE);

textSendTime = new Text(taskingInputsGroup, SWT.BORDER);
textSubject = new Text(taskingInputsGroup, SWT.BORDER);
textTaskStartTime = new Text(taskingInputsGroup, SWT.BORDER);
```

I'm trying to set a `private Control` field for an Enum's constants to each of these `Text` objects:

```
textSendTime = new Text(taskingInputsGroup, SWT.BORDER);  
MsgField.SEND_TIME.setControl(textSendTime);
```

In the Enum, I just have a simple getter/setter for the `Control` field.

I have a method that is called when a user presses a `Button`. This method loops through the Enum constants and sets the text of some `TreeItem`s to whatever is in the `Control` objects:

```
MsgField[] msgFields= MsgField.values();
for (int i = 0; i < msgFields.length; i++) {
    Control control = msgFields[i].getControl();
    if (control != null) {
        if (control instanceof Text) {
            root.getItem(i).getItem(0).setText(((Text)control).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

---

### My Question

I am getting empty text from `((Text)control).getText()` even if there is text in the `Text` field. Why could this be? I know I'm overlooking something simple (it's been a long day). I've read a bunch of SO posts on Java passing by value, but I can't seem to apply the answers to this issue. This works fine if I call `getText()` directly on the object in my view class:

```
root.getItem(1).getItem(0).setText(textSendTime.getText());
```

EDIT - Some `MsgField` enum code:

```
public enum MsgField {

    private boolean isRequiredField;
    private String treeName;

    public abstract void setValue(Msg msg, String value);
    public abstract Object getValue(Msg msg);

    private MsgField(boolean req, String name) {
        isRequiredField = req;
        treeName = name;
    }

    SEND_TIME("Send Time", true) {
        @Override
        public void setValue(Msg msg, String value) {
            msg.setSendTime(value);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValue(Msg msg) {
            return msg.getSendTime();
        }
    },

    // ....
    // other fields
    // ....

    START_TIME("Start Time", false) {
        @Override
        public void setValue(Msg msg, String value) {
            msg.setStartTime(value);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValue(Msg msg) {
            return msg.getStartTime();
        }
    };
}
```

So the idea here is to represent the fields for the `Msg` class and have these get/set methods for each one so that I can easily iterate over them and get/set the fields for my `Msg` object. This worked fine (although maybe you can suggest a better alternative), but the trouble came with the addition of that `Control` field as I mentioned.

Comment: Hard to say exactly, but this might be a concurrency issue because you seem to be using a stateful `enum` (`MessageField` or is it `MsgField`?), which is a [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540293/should-enum-objects-be-stateless), because `enum`s are essentially global variables.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. This application lets the user populate an object by filling out `Text` and `Combo` fields, then it serializes the object it to a JSON file. Each enum constant represented a field in the aforementioned object, and this simplified many operations in my program. I was attempting to further simplify it by associating the `Text` and `Combo` inputs for each field with the enum constants that they mapped to. What could be another alternative?

Comment: The enum was fairly simple at first, but now adding this seems to be doing too much. Should I just create a class that maps to this object I'm trying to serialize instead of an enum?

Comment: Enums are very useful, but you would need to know their state at compile time. Perhaps if you add some more code it would be easier to give suggestions.

Comment: Just added some code for `MsgField`, thanks for the help!

Comment: I have tried your code and got it to work... So I suppose you are on the right track? Are you absolutely sure the Controls are not overwritten by another Control at some point? (Debug and check the object ids). Are you opening two views accidentally? While this code works I would not store Controls in enums. What happens when you close your view and these controls are disposed? You are stuck with disposed objects in your Enum. Or if you open two views only one of them will work. I would find a better way to do this

Comment: I'm only instantiating one `Control` per field and passing it to the enum; they aren't getting overwritten. Only one view can be open at a time, and each one has its associated enum. I do agree that there is probably a better way to handle this, but I'm not really sure what it is.