# Android singleton not losing his state after app's onDestroy

Tags: java, android, singleton, ondestroy

My app makes use of a singleton object implemented like this

```
enum MySingleton extends Something{

    INSTANCE{}

    <a bunch of attributes declared here>

    public void method1();

    public void method2();

    (...)

}
```

What I've watched is after my app is closed and I run the app again, my singleton attributes weren't reset

Because I'm using this pattern's implementation from Java 6 (if I'm not wrong), can I say this is equivalent to the private static singleton implementation from the previous Java releases, and in this I have to manually reset his state inside app's onDestroy()?

Comment: "What I've watched is after my app is closed and I run the app again, my singleton attributes weren't reset" -- that is because [your process was not terminated](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes). "I have to manually reset his state inside app's onDestroy()?" -- an "app" does not have `onDestroy()`.

Comment: As app I mean app's first activity, in my case MapsActivity, where my SupportMapFragment is

Comment: In Android, the lifecycle of activities and the lifecycle of processes are not related. When activities come and go is independent of when processes come and go.

Comment: "my singleton attributes weren't reset" I'd just like to point out that mutable state in an enum is [a pretty bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/540293/3788176).

Comment: @CommonsWare, got it =)

Comment: @Andy, so after Java 6 the main idea about implementing a singleton using enum is for stateless singletons? In the case of stateful singletons should I use the old way to implement it?

Comment: @TadeuAriasVillares I don't know what you mean by "the old way", but you shouldn't use enums for this - and I would also suggest [you might not want to use a singleton, really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Comment: Thanks for your support guys =)

Comment: Btw what's the best alternative for singleton?