# Binding an enum's toString() to a Label

Tags: javafx, binding, enums, label

I have set up my application to change its function based on an enum. The value of a variable linked to this enum will determine how the program interprets certain actions like mouse clicks and so on. I would like a Label (perhaps in the status area in the bottom left) to reflect what the current "mode" the application is in, and display a readable message for the user to see.

Here's my enum:

```
enum Mode {
    defaultMode,     // Example states that will determine
    alternativeMode; // how the program interprets mouse clicks

    // My attempt at making a property that a label could bind to
    private SimpleStringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "myEnumProp", "Initial Text");
    public SimpleStringProperty getProperty() {return property;}

    // Override of the toString() method to display prettier text
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        switch(this) {
            case defaultMode:
                return "Default mode";
            default:
                return "Alternative mode";
        }
    }
}
```

From what I've gathered, what I'm looking for is a way to bind an enum's toString() property (which I overrode into more digestable form) to this label. The binding would be so that whenever I set something like

```
applicationState = Mode.alternativeMode;
```

the label will display the `toString()` results automatically, without me needing to place a `leftStatus.setText(applicationState.toString())` every time I do that.

Here's what I've tried: (in my main controller class):

```
leftStatus.textProperty().bind(applicationState.getProperty());
```

That sets the label to the initial text, but won't update when I update the `applicationState` enum.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of adding a property to the enum class, why not use a [`ObjectProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) for the application state? Have a look at this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    private ObjectProperty<Mode> appState = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Mode.DEFAULT);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button btn = new Button("Toggle mode");
        btn.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> appState.setValue(appState.get() == Mode.DEFAULT ? Mode.ALTERNATIVE : Mode.DEFAULT));

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.textProperty().bind(appState.asString());

        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(btn, lbl);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public enum Mode {
        DEFAULT("Default mode"),
        ALTERNATIVE("Alternative mode");

        private String description;

        private Mode(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and exactly what I need. For any future people who might stumble upon this, I might add that I had to adjust my switch statements (for when I checked which mode I was in) to add in a .get() at the end. Everything else works flawlessly. Thank you both for your answers, I'll choose this one as the best because it's the most elegant and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`asString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ObjectExpression.html#asString--) to get a `StringBinding` from a `Property<Mode>` containing the value of the property converted to `String` using the object's `toString` method.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<Mode> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    combo.getItems().setAll(Mode.values());
    Label label = new Label();

    // use "state" property from combo box
    // (you could replace combo.valueProperty() with your own property)
    label.textProperty().bind(combo.valueProperty().asString());

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(combo, label), 200, 200);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Otherwise, if you want the property value contained in the enum, you could use `Bindings.selectString`, provided you rename the `getProperty()` method to `propertyProperty()` to adhere the naming conventions:

```
enum Mode {
    ...

    public StringProperty propertyProperty() {return property;}
    ...
}
```

```
private final Random random = new Random();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<Mode> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    combo.getItems().setAll(Mode.values());
    Label label = new Label();

    // use "state" property from combo box
    // (you could replace combo.valueProperty() with your own property)
    label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.selectString(combo.valueProperty(), "property"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(combo, label), 200, 200);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        // change property values at random
        Mode.defaultMode.propertyProperty().set(random.nextBoolean() ? "a" : "b");
        Mode.alternativeMode.propertyProperty().set(random.nextBoolean() ? "c" : "d");
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think [enums should be stateless](http://stackoverflow.com/q/540293/3429133) and, therefore, shouldn't offer bindable properties.