# Why are my enum fields being serialized?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

According to [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6469), enum constants' fields are not serialized. So I put together the following demo:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

enum EnumBasedSingleton
{
  INSTANCE;

  EnumBasedSingleton() {
    value = 42;
  }

  int value;

  public int getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }
  public void setValue(int value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class EnumBasedSingletonDemo
{
  static void saveToFile(EnumBasedSingleton singleton, String filename)
    throws Exception
  {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut))
    {
      out.writeObject(singleton);
    }
  }

  static EnumBasedSingleton readFromFile(String filename)
    throws Exception
  {
    try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn) )
    {
      return (EnumBasedSingleton)in.readObject();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    EnumBasedSingleton singleton = EnumBasedSingleton.INSTANCE;
    singleton.setValue(111);
    String filename = "myfile.bin";
    saveToFile(singleton, filename);
    EnumBasedSingleton singleton2 = readFromFile(filename);
    System.out.println(singleton2.getValue());
  }
}
```

I was expecting the output to be `42` but what I got is `111`. Am I misunderstanding the document or are enum constants' fields serialized? I'm running this in Java 9.

Comment: Why were you expecting 42?

Comment: @shmosel because the constructor specifies this value

Comment: Enums are singletons. The document states _The serialized form of an enum constant consists solely of its name;_ It follows that, during deserialization, the name is used to determine the enum constant by name. That enum constant, in your current process, has a `value` value of 111. No constructor is invoked.

Comment: It's not calling the constructor. It's the same instance.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ooh, I think I get it. so if I restart the process and deserialize, I'll get whatever value the constructor give me. thanks!

Comment: That’s right. But you really shouldn’t be putting mutable state in enum constants. Such issues wouldn’t come up.

Answer (score 0):

There is only ever one instance of an `enum` constant during the lifetime of a java process.

The document you linked states

> The serialized form of an `enum` constant consists solely of its name;
>   field values of the constant are not present in the form. To serialize
>   an `enum` constant, `ObjectOutputStream` writes the value returned by the
>   `enum` constant's `name` method. To deserialize an `enum` constant,
>   `ObjectInputStream` reads the constant name from the stream; the
>   deserialized constant is then obtained by calling the
>   `java.lang.Enum.valueOf` method, passing the constant's `enum` type along
>   with the received constant name as arguments.

In other words, the constant's name is used to retrieve the appropriate instance. That instance, however, is the same instance you serialized, it's not a new instance, the `enum` constructor was not invoked again. And since you had changed the state of the `enum` constant earlier, you're seeing that changed value.

Had you started a new java process and tried to deserialize the contents of that file without touching the `enum` constant, you would have seen its original value of 42.

---

The misunderstanding might stem from using mutable state in your enums. [That's strongly discouraged.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540293/should-enum-objects-be-stateless)